# Address in mailbox given [c] does not comply with RFC 2822, Laravel, Swiftmailer

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I want to add bcc mail to my Laravel 8 mailing system. Before I add bcc it works as it should.

Then in `MailMessage.php` I change this:

```
class MailMessage extends SimpleMessage implements Renderable
{
    use Conditionable;
    /**
     * The "bcc" information for the message.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $bcc = ['clovc12345@gmail.com'];
}
```

And I get this error:

```
 "message": "Address in mailbox given [c] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.",
    "exception": "Swift_RfcComplianceException",
    "file": "C:\\Users\\Softnet\\Desktop\\MojSoftnet\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Mime\\Headers\\MailboxHeader.php",
    "line": 355,
```

Same for: `public $bcc = ['clovc12345@gmail.com', 'MyName'];`

Comment: Looks like the`bcc` property should be an array of arrays, so it is indexing into 'clovc12345@gmail.com', hence getting 'c' as the email address. Try something like `[['clovc12345@gmail.com', 'MyName']]`.

Comment: See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/43ed474c14085125d66cc6b534a654eac43c5160/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/MailMessage.php#L221 for example.